# How can I add a timer on Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I'm looking for a way to add a timer (or stopwatch) that will start counting from 0 the moment the application is launched or a button is clicked, and keeps counting even after the user navigates through different pages, and then be able to display how much time has passed in the last page of the application. I've been messing around with the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class, but to be honest, I'm having trouble understanding it. Any help, or even a nod in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a time, you could add one on the page showing time!

Add this code to the constructor or somewhere else where you want to activate the timer. (The App.StartTime is the same as i wrote in the other answer)

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        timer.Tick +=
            delegate(object s, EventArgs args)
            {
                TimeSpan time = (DateTime.Now - App.StartTime);

                this.timenow.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
            };

        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // one second
        timer.Start();
```

Comment: No , I want one to be running in the background and for all pages not just for one page.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to store the time when your app launch and then subtract the current time from the stored value.

in your App.cs store the time when application launch:

```
    private static DateTime _starttime = DateTime.Now;

    public static DateTime StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _starttime;
        }
    }
```

In your page or any where you need to get the current time the application has run, you just have to subtract then current time from the stored time. I have used it in a button click handler, see below:

```
    private void timebutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan time = (DateTime.Now - App.StartTime);

        this.timenow.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
    }
```

Comment: This is excellent, it works like a charm. However, I must ask one more thing: Is there a way to refresh the time shown automatically (like every second instead of having to click the button for a refresh)

Comment: I want it for all pages please not just one page.